# Pilha dinâmica em C não compila por causa de tipos de char incompatíveis

Tags: c

Estou fazendo um tema em que tenho que nomear documentos em uma pilha dinâmica, empilhar elas e imprimir os nomes de documentos. O nome dos documentos ficam em uma variável "char arquivos[20]" na struct. 
Eu criei as funções e a lista estaria funcionando se não fosse por um erro: "[Error] incompatible types in assignment of 'char*' to 'char [20]". Esse erro acontece na **linha 22** do código que está mostrado aqui em baixo.

Tentei de diversas formas tentar converter as variáveis para que fossem compatíveis uma com a outra, mas sem sucesso.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Pilha
{
    char arquivos[20];
    struct Pilha *prox;
};

typedef struct Pilha PILHA;
typedef PILHA *pilha;

void empilhar(pilha *topo, char arquivos[])
{
    pilha novono;
    novono=(pilha)malloc(sizeof(struct Pilha));
    if (novono == NULL)
    printf("\nNão foi possível alocar, pois não tem memoria disponivel!");
    else
    {
        novono->arquivos=arquivos; //O erro acontece aqui!
        novono->prox=*topo;
        *topo=novono;
    }
}

void mostrandodocumentos(pilha files)
{
    if (files == NULL)
    printf("A pilha esta sem arquivos!");
    else
    {
        printf("\nArquivos: \n\n");
        do
        {
            printf("%s.txt\n",files->prox);
            files=files->prox;
        }while (files!=NULL);
    }
}

int main()
{
    pilha doc=NULL;
    char nomefile[20];

    printf("Declare o nome do documento:");
    scanf("%s",&nomefile);
    empilhar(&doc, nomefile);
    mostrandodocumentos(doc);
}
```

Agradeço desde já pela ajuda! Essa é a primeira vez que crio uma pergunta aqui.

Comment: char * é um ponteiro para char. char[20] é a vigésima primeira posição do array de char.

Comment: Para se copiar uma string em C, uma cadeia de caracteres com o terminador '\0', utiliza-se a função strcpy de <string.h> e não uma simples atribuição (=).

Comment: Aqui: scanf("%s",&nomefile); não tem este & nomefile já é um endereço (o endereço da primeira posição do array). Utilize scanf("%s", nomefile);

Answer (score 0):

Tem vários erros no programa, e a escolha de nomes é muito ruim (Pilha, pilha, PILHA ???)

Aqui vai uma versão com algumas correções.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Pilha
{
  char arquivos[20];
  struct Pilha* prox;
} Pilha;

static void empilhar(Pilha** topo, char arquivos[])
{
  Pilha* novo_no = malloc(sizeof(Pilha));
  if (novo_no == NULL)
    printf("\nNão foi possível alocar, pois não tem memoria disponivel!");
  else
  {
    strcpy(novo_no->arquivos, arquivos);
    novo_no->prox = *topo;
    *topo = novo_no;
  }
}

static void mostrarDocumentos(Pilha* files)
{
  if (files == NULL)
    printf("A pilha esta sem arquivos!");
  else
  {
    printf("\nArquivos: \n\n");
    do
    {
      printf("%s.txt\n",files->arquivos);
      files = files->prox;
    } while (files != NULL);
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  Pilha* doc = NULL;
  char nomefile[20];

  printf("Declare o nome do documento:");
  scanf("%s", nomefile);
  empilhar(&doc, nomefile);
  mostrarDocumentos(doc);
}
```